# How to terminate applet gracefully?

Tags: java, browser, applet, exit

My applet is supposed to take external parameters from html file which might be dynamically generated.

```
<param name="type1" value="value1">
<param name="type2" value="value2">
```

Those parameters has to be checked for validity in `Applet.init()`

```
String type1 = getParameter("type1");
String type2 = getParameter("type2");
if (type1 == null || type2 == null) ....
```

And they are wrong what should I do? **Is it okay to call `Applet.destroy()` manually?**

As I know `stop` and `destroy` are supposed to be called by browser, not applet itself.

Comment: `stop` and `destory` are notifications send to your applet by the browser, calling them yourself won't make any difference.  Applets don't have a concept of termination like a desktop app does, the best you can do is have a branch in you program that puts up a message about why the application can't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Applet.destroy()` should only be called by the JVM.

The best strategy here is to redirect to a page that shows the parameters and what is wrong with them.  To do that, use something like:

```
URL brokenParams = new URL(this.getDocumentBase(), 
    "badparams.html?type1=" + type1 + "&type2=" + type2);
this.getAppletContext().showDocument(brokenParams);
```

This will have the effect that:

- The applet page will vanish, replaced by..
- `badparam.html` which shows the params and describes the problem. Then..
- When the JVM browser combo. decides it is the right time, the `Applet.destroy()` method will be called.  (The 'right time' is typically 30-60 seconds later by my reckoning.)

Comment: so what would happen to the code in `init` which follows `this.getAppletContext().showDocument` ? would it be executed or not?

Comment: *"would it be executed or not?"*  To the best of my understanding, no.

Comment: ok, thanks for your quick reply. just in case I would add `return` after `showDocument`.